# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Vue'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have read multiple answers to similar questions, however with most solutions being an improper workaround. I would please like assistance with an explanation / solution to why this is error occurring on **all instances of `this`**:

> Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Vue'

Component where it is occurring **(note if I remove the computed property `showModal` there are no longer any errors)**:

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog id="edit-cattle" v-model="showModal" persistent scrollable max-width="600px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">Edit Cattle</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-form v-model="valid">
            <v-container>
              <v-select id="status" :items="statusOptions" label="Status" v-model="client.status"></v-select>
            </v-container>
          </v-form>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import firebase, { firestore } from "firebase/app";
import constants from "../constants/constants";
import {
  Client,
  ClientLegalType,
  ClientStatus,
  Month,
  ClientBank,
  ClientBankAccountType
} from "../models/client.model";
import helpers from "../helpers/helpers";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "EditClient",
  props: {
    client: Object as () => Client,
    showModalValue: Boolean
  },
  data() {
    return {
      postalSameAsPhysical: false,
      valid: false,
      loading: false,
      registrationDate: (this.client
        ?.registrationDate as firebase.firestore.Timestamp)
        ?.toDate()
        .toISOString()
        .substr(0, 10),
      legalTypeOptions: Object.keys(ClientLegalType).map(value => {
        return { text: helpers.camelToWords(value), value: value };
      }),
      statusOptions: Object.keys(ClientStatus).map(value => {
        return { text: helpers.camelToWords(value), value: value };
      }),
      monthOptions: Object.keys(Month).map(value => {
        return { text: helpers.camelToWords(value), value: value };
      }),
      bankOptions: Object.keys(ClientBank).map(value => {
        return { text: helpers.camelToWords(value), value: value };
      }),
      bankAccountTypeOptions: Object.keys(ClientBankAccountType).map(value => {
        return { text: helpers.camelToWords(value), value: value };
      })
    };
  },
  methods: {
    passData() {
      const updatedClient: Client = {
        ...this.client //Property 'client' does not exist on type 'Vue'
      };
      //Property 'registrationDate' does not exist on type 'Vue'
      if (this.registrationDate) {
        updatedClient.registrationDate = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(
          new Date(this.registrationDate)
        );
      }
      console.log("updatedClient: ", updatedClient);
      this.showModal = false; //Property 'showModal' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
      this.$emit("saveData", helpers.undefinedToNull(updatedClient));
    }
  },
  computed: {
    algoliaClient(): any {
      const client = algoliasearch(
        constants.ALGOLIA.APP_ID,
        constants.ALGOLIA.SEARCH_KEY
      );
      return client.initIndex(constants.ALGOLIA.INDEXES.CLIENTS);
    },
    showModal: {
      get(): Boolean {
        return this.showModalValue //Property 'showModalValue' does not exist on type '(() => any) | ComputedOptions<any>'.;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("updateShowModalValue", value); //Property '$emit' does not exist on type '(() => any) | ComputedOptions<any>'.
      }
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

My config files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "vuetify"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^4.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "firebase": "^7.19.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended',
    '@vue/prettier',
    '@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  },
};
```

shims-tsx.d.ts

```
import Vue, { VNode } from "vue";

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    // tslint:disable no-empty-interface
    interface Element extends VNode {}
    // tslint:disable no-empty-interface
    interface ElementClass extends Vue {}
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      [elem: string]: any;
    }
  }
}
```

shims-vue.d.ts

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

Comment: The errors are fixed when I type the set method in the computed property showModal: set(value: boolean). Would still appreciate an explanation as to why this occurs as it is a misleading error.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to type and set default values for the props that you are getting onto the component, specially under TypeScript.

The problem here is because of your type definition of the computed property, it's expecting to return a false, but `showModalValue` prop has not a default value. So it is initally `undefined`, with plain javascript undefined is falsey, but not in TypeScript.

Set the prop by default to `false` and the error should be gone.

Comment: thank you. have tried giving 'showModalValue' a default value of false, still same errors.however when I change the set method of showModal from 'set(value)' too 'set(value: boolean)' all errors are gone. Not sure what Typescript mechanics are causing this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, only on one of several components even if they are written in the same way... weird.

I finally fixed that by typing the entire `options` object passed to `Vue.extend` with `ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue, DefaultData<any>, DefaultMethods<any>, DefaultComputed, DefaultProps>`.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import {
  DefaultComputed,
  DefaultData,
  DefaultMethods,
  DefaultProps,
  ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps
} from "vue/types/options";

Vue.extend({
  ...
} as ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue, DefaultData<any>, DefaultMethods<any>, DefaultComputed, DefaultProps>)
```